# Haskell - How to get a List of Tuples with certain combinations

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is there a way to create a list of tuples with a certain pattern?

I have following inputs for example:

```
a = 100

b = [10,20,30]

c = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
```

And I would like to have following Output:

```
[(100,10,'a'),(100,10,'b'),(100,10,'c'),(100,10,'d'),(100,10,'e'),(100,10,'f'),(100,10,'g'),
 (100,20,'a'),(100,20,'b'),(100,20,'c'),(100,20,'d'),(100,20,'e'),(100,20,'f'),(100,20,'g'),
 (100,30,'a'),(100,30,'b'),(100,30,'c'),(100,30,'d'),(100,30,'e'),(100,30,'f'),(100,30,'g')]
```

I think if I only had **a** and **b** for example I would do:

```
makeTuple :: Int -> [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
makeTuple _ [] = []
makeTuple i (x:xs) = [(i,x)] ++ makeTuple i xs
```

This would give me:

```
[(100,10),(100,20),(100,30)]
```

Im not sure how I could make it work with 3 Inputs .

Comment: ^ 3 lists would work the same way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List comprehensions can do it nicely:

```
[(a, x, y) | x <- b, y <- c]
```

Comment: I like this better than my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Applicative.html) composition:

```
ghci> (,,) <$> [a] <*> b <*> c
[(100,10,'a'),(100,10,'b'),(100,10,'c'),(100,10,'d'),(100,10,'e'),(100,10,'f'),(100,10,'g'),
 (100,20,'a'),(100,20,'b'),(100,20,'c'),(100,20,'d'),(100,20,'e'),(100,20,'f'),(100,20,'g'),
 (100,30,'a'),(100,30,'b'),(100,30,'c'),(100,30,'d'),(100,30,'e'),(100,30,'f'),(100,30,'g')]
```

Here's an explanation of how that works, with examples in F#, Haskell, and C#: [An applicative password list](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/10/15/an-applicative-password-list).

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the Answer I will check out your link!